# Registry entry missing for msexchangeDSAccess exchange 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, best-practices, windows-registry

After running exbpa i received a notification for PDC emulator is not excluded active directory access (ADAccess) topology with the value for minuserdc is missing

after researching how to fix, I am supposed to navigate to

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeDSAccess\Profiles\Default

and create the minuserdc with a certain value

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeDSAccess\Profiles\Default

does not exist in the registry on the exchange 2010 system.

should I just create this registry path and then add the minuserDC, or is this a bigger problem that this doesnt exist in general?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found this on microsoft technet. it appears in SP1 of exchange 2010 they removed the registry entries for this setting, but did not update the expba to follow along with it.